# Question about " What do we put on the back"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does it mean? Is it an idiom? 
I saw it on BBC. 
Does it talk about forgetting something? Or holding or writing something on a banner in a demonstration. I just saw it in subtitle and the programe was over.

Comment: What was that program about? Could be anything - right from we put *a bag* on the back while traveling to we put luggage on the back (of a mule!)...my imagination has no limit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It normally refers to the other side of a sheet of paper, or, like you mentioned, a banner. Both have two sides. When they talk about what to 'put on the back', they mean what they should write on the back side of the banner.